# Sockets: Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I want to reuse a socket after I used it once, but I always get subj exception.
I found multiple questions with same issue but no working solution. I tried `using` code, i tried manual closing - but without any success

A little sample

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace SocketTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
                var host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
                var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(host.AddressList[0], 11322);
                Console.WriteLine("Iteration #{0}\tEnpdoint = {1}", i, endpoint);
                try
                {

                    var client = new TcpClient(endpoint);

                    const string message = "Hello world!";
                    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(message);
                    client.Connect(endpoint);
                    var stream = client.GetStream();

                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);


                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];
                    int totalBytes = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(receiveData, 0, receiveData.Length);
                        totalBytes += bytesRead;
                        if (bytesRead < receiveData.Length)
                            break;
                        Array.Resize(ref receiveData, 2 * receiveData.Length);
                    }

                    var response = encoding.GetString(receiveData, 0, totalBytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", response);

                    client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    client.Client.Disconnect(true);
                    stream.Close();
                    client.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the code does not match the exception. It is the server that is throwing an exception not the client. You are never calling start on any listener here with this code.

Comment: I am sorry but that is totally unreadable to me, your dos box, but it shows a different exception than before. Here i can recognize tcpclient iso tcplistener.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I'm sorry because there is no easy way to localize exception messages. But it's an exception that i wrote in subject. I posted this screenshot for a stacktrace only, and as proof that first iteration is working fine, but second fails. It means that some resources are not disposed.

Comment: _"there is no easy way to localize exception messages"_ -- Actually, there's a very easy way to _translate_ exception messages (which have already been localized for your benefit). Just copy/paste to translator.bing.com's landing page. It does quite well with text from Microsoft's technical documentation. _"I posted this screenshot for a stacktrace only"_ -- as Philip has pointed out, that stack trace doesn't match the error you claim to be getting. There's no reason for a call to `Connect()` to throw `Only one usage of each socket address...`

Comment: But it is. `Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)` translation is `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.` See screenshot http://i.imgur.com/ct00etP.png . It shouldn't throw an exception if I disposed all resourced, but it throws. I dunno what else can I dispose